# Validate GitCommit Message when PR

Tags: azure-devops

I have an Azure DevOps Pipeline where I wanted to check the commit message should follow a pattern.

I can use the below command, but the problem with the command is it will list other PR commits to and will not able to pin point to the PR trigger. not sure how to get the commit message for a particular PR from Azure DevOps Pipline.

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit
```

Comment: Hi, You can use variable `Build.SourceVersionMessage` directly to get the commit message. Please check out below answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) `$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)` directly in your pipepline to get the commit message associated to the PR.

```
steps:    
- powershell: echo "$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)"
```

You can also use below git commands to get the commit message for a particular commit.

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit -n 1 <commitId>
```

So to get the commit message of the pr commit. You can use the predefined variable `$(Build.SourceVersion)`. See below:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
    git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit -n 1 $(Build.SourceVersion)
```

After you get the commit message you can do the validation in your PR pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pr` [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#pr-triggers) to have specific build to validate commits on PR like this:

```yaml
pr:
- master
- releases/*
```

and then use `Build.SourceVersion` to get message Id

And having this you can implement logic to validate message.

[image]

Comment: You may want to note: This is only possible for GitHub repositories. It does not apply to Azure Repos git repositories for example.